# Making good looking latex table

Tags: tables, xetex

I would like to get :
[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,multirow}
%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}


% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
Script=Bengali,
Language=Bengali,
AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]



%End--------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering 
\caption{নামাজ রােজার চিরস্থায়ী ক্যালেন্ডার}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
মাস     & তারিখ & সেহরির শেষ সময়  &  ফজর আরম্ভ  & সূর্যোদয় ও ফজরের শেষ সময়  & জোহরের সময় আরম্ভ  & আসরের সময় আরম্ভ  & মাগরিব ও ইফতারের সময়   & এশার সময় আরম্ভ  \\ \hline\hline
  \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{জানুয়ারী}} &  ১     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &  ৫     & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\ \cline{2-9}  
&  ১০      & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\ \cline{2-9}
&  ১৫     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &  ২০      & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\ \cline{2-9}  
&  ২৫     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\  \hline\hline
                          
  \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ফেব্রুয়ারী}} &  ১     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &  ৫     & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\ \cline{2-9}  
&  ১০      & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\ \cline{2-9}
&  ১৫     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\ \cline{2-9} 
 &  ২০      & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\ \cline{2-9}  
&  ২৫     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২    \\  \hline\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image]

How can I get required table?

Comment: That depends on what it is that you want. For example, what decides the colour of the column?

Comment: @  Plergux Color is not important here.

Answer (score 3):

Let me preface my answer by stating that I cannot read or write Bengali characters. My answer may therefore well be missing important considerations. Sorry.

My immediate reaction to the template you posted was, "wow, the color scheme looks really baroque". I would like to suggest that you *not* try to replicate the four or five different shades of gray. Instead, just focus on providing an open and inviting 'look', say, by getting rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,multirow}
%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
%\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

% Times New Roman used for English
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}

% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
Script=Bengali,
Language=Bengali,
AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]

%% new:
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[skip=0.25\baselineskip,font=Large]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\caption*{নামাজ রােজার চিরস্থায়ী ক্যালেন্ডার}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} c @{\quad} c *{7}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} @{}}
\toprule
মাস  & তারিখ & সেহরির শেষ সময়  &  ফজর আরম্ভ  & সূর্যোদয়~ও ফজরের শেষ সময়  & জোহরের সময় আরম্ভ  & আসরের সময় আরম্ভ  & মাগরিব~ও ইফতারের সময়   & এশার সময় আরম্ভ  \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{জানুয়ারী}} &  ১     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩ &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
&  ৫       & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
&  ১০     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\ 
&  ১৫     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
&  ২০     & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
&  ২৫     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\  
\midrule                      
\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ফেব্রুয়ারী}} &  ১     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩ &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
&  ৫       & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
&  ১০     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\ 
&  ১৫     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
&  ২০     & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
&  ২৫     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২    \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`. You need the latest version of `nicematrix` (v 5.15 of 2021-04-25).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,tabularx,multirow}
%--------------------------------------------------
%Bengali Font in Document
%--------------------------------------------------
\tracinglostchars=2
% For a bilingual document
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX, Scale=MatchUppercase}
% Times New Roman used for English
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[NFSSFamily=ntxtlf]
\setmainlanguage{bengali}
\setotherlanguage{english}


% Bengali
\newfontfamily\bengalifont{Kalpurush}[
Script=Bengali,
Language=Bengali,
AutoFakeBold = 0.2,
AutoFakeSlant = 0.15  ]

\usepackage{nicematrix}

%End--------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MyColumnColor}{mm}   
  { \rectanglecolor[gray]{#2}{1-#1}{1-#1} 
       % the row 2 is a dummy row 
    \rectanglecolor[gray]{#2}{3-#1}{8-#1} 
       % the row 9 is a dummy row
    \rectanglecolor[gray]{#2}{10-#1}{15-#1} }

\centering 
\caption{নামাজ রােজার চিরস্থায়ী ক্যালেন্ডার}
\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\color{white}}m{6mm}@{\hskip2pt}c*8{m{1cm}}}[rules/color=gray]
\CodeBefore
   \MyColumnColor{1}{0.4}
   % the column number 2 is a dummy column
   \MyColumnColor{3}{0.9}
   \MyColumnColor{4}{0.95}
   \MyColumnColor{5}{0.8}
   \MyColumnColor{6}{0.9}
   \MyColumnColor{7}{0.95}
   \MyColumnColor{8}{0.8}
   \MyColumnColor{9}{0.9}
   \MyColumnColor{10}{0.95}
\Body
   \Block[hvlines]{}{}
   মাস     &&
   \Block[hvlines]{1-}{}
    তারিখ & সেহরির শেষ সময়  &  ফজর আরম্ভ  & সূর্যোদয় ও ফজরের শেষ সময়  & জোহরের সময় আরম্ভ  & আসরের সময় আরম্ভ  &
   মাগরিব ও ইফতারের সময়   & এশার সময় আরম্ভ  \\[-2.5mm] \\
   \Block[borders={top,left,bottom}]{6-1}{}
   \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{জানুয়ারী}} &&  
   \Block[hvlines]{6-*}{}
   ১     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
   &&  ৫     & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
   &&  ১০      & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\ 
   &&  ১৫     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
   &&  ২০      & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
   &&  ২৫     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\[-2.5mm]  \\
   \Block[borders={top,left,bottom}]{6-1}{}
   \multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{ফেব্রুয়ারী}} &&  
   \Block[hvlines]{6-*}{}
   ১     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
   &&  ৫     & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
   &&  ১০      & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২  \\ 
   &&  ১৫     & ৫-১৪ & ৫-১৯   & ৬-৪১  & ১২-০৩  &  ৩-৪৯ & ৫-৩০  & ৬-৪৬  \\  
   &&  ২০      & ৫-১৫ & ৫-২০   & ৬-৪২   & ১২-০৫   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৩   & ৬-৪৯   \\   
   &&  ২৫     & ৫-১৬ & ৫-২১  & ৬-৪৩   & ১২-০৭   &  ৩-৫২  & ৫-৩৬    & ৬-৫২    \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]